# Custom ViewHandler to override javax.faces.viewstate hidden field value

Tags: jsf-2

Can we change the value of the inputHidden field "javax.faces.viewState" before the page render.

For the field

The value should be changed to a different length value. Can this be done by using a custom viewHandler?

Can we achieve this by extending the class to ResponseWriter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field is rendered by the ResponseStateManager that you obtain from the current render kit.

If you look up its API you'll see that you can't just override the field's value. You have to replace the entire thing! Since state saving is quite complex (think about both server and client algos), I would think twice about attempting this.

An alternative is using a Servlet filter to capture the entire response. The hidden field's name is standardized and you could search and replace on it. For a postback you could use the same filter to restore the param.

Comment: Can we override the createView method in ViewHandler to find the viewstate element and update the value?

Comment: No, it generates a tree, not a string. The only other alternative is setting a buffering response writer and grab the same string, do replacement, then write back. This is almost the same as the filter, but you might be able to grab a smaller section.